# How to avoid refetching when using reduxToolkit rtk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Hi all I have following code. I am new in reduxToolkit rtk and hope you can help to find solution to my question.

I have following code.
So with this code I am creating `posts` endpoint.

```
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

    export const postsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "postsApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
     }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
    posts: builder.query({ query: () => "/posts" }),
    }),
    });

    export const { usePostsQuery } = postsApi;
```

This is my store.

```
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { postsApi } from "./services/postsApi";

     export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
     [postsApi.reducerPath]: postsApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postsApi.middleware),
    });
```

And this is where I am getting my data.

```
    const Home = () => {
      const count = useSelector(
        (state) => state?.postsApi?.queries?.["posts(undefined)"]?.data
      );

      const { data, error, isLoading, isFetching, isSuccess } = usePostsQuery();

      return (
        <>
          {isSuccess && console.log("data", data)} 
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Home;
```

So when I am fetching the data, it stored in store , so after every time when `<Home />` component is mounting I am again fetching that data from backend, I want to avoid that fetching because I already have that data my store. How can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be such refetching happening - is this an assumption you have or are you really seeing that in the network tab?

Comment: Yes I see in network....I have 2 routes. First is `Home` (in this component `get data` was implemented and second is `about` route ... when I am going from about to home I can see in my network tab second time get data

Comment: In that case, is your Redux store reinitializing from empty on that navigation? That sometimes happens when navigation is set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if trigger the same query as an existing one, no request will be performed.

If you need, you can force a refetch. You can call refetch that is returned by the hook.

You can find more details on [RTK Queries Docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries)